# PHP General SQL Query and Results similar to PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble creating a general MySQLi query box, where the results, regardless of the type of query, are output in another textarea - similar to the textarea from the SQL tab in PHPMyAdmin.

For example:

- I would like to display a textarea on my page.
- User enters ANY MySQL code, whether it be SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.
- Results are displayed in a results textarea, for example, if they enter a SELECT query, they get the results, if they enter a DELETE, they will get a # of deletions.
- Functions just like the SQL tab of PHPMyAdmin.

Is there a simplified way to do this? Or do I need to detect their query, and return results depending on an algorithm that I have to write (which I can do, I'm just trying to avoid all that coding).

This is what I've tried last:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $pw, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "BAD CONNECTION!";
        } else {
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        print_r($result);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    $mysqli->close();
```

I also tried:

```
echo $result
```

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried? StackOverflow isn't here to write code for you.

Comment: @Enijar Actually you should read the question. Although I wouldn't say this is top quality, OP isn't asking for code.

Comment: Do you want to achieve something like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @enijar - I was hoping to avoid an API - I can just write the code myself and save a lot of overhead. I was just curious if it was just a simple mysqi function, or similar.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is open source, right?  So maybe you should look at how they do it.

Comment: I looked at their GitHub - it's just too overwhelmingly big. I'm just going to assume that there is no simple way due to the lack of answers, and just code it out by detecting the string(s), etc. Thanks for all your help guys/girls! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do what you need. Try to use some PHP open source DB libraries like DiBi (http://dibiphp.com/cs/). But you will still need to write some code. This just makes it easier.